# How to run the file after transfer using scp command in ubuntu?

Tags: server

When I am using the scp command

```
scp username@ipadd:/lab/home/Desktop && chmod 777 filename && ./filename
```

and

```
scp username@ipadd:/lab/home/Desktop | chmod 777 filename | ./filename
```

in both commands only file is transfer but the privileges of the file is not changed or even file is not running.

Comment: Please do not use 777. 750 is more than enough. Or better 700. I am missing a bit in your 1st part `scp username@ipadd:/lab/home/Desktop/filename filename`  Otherwise the file might not be called `filename` when it reaches `chmod`. Does the command show any errors?

Comment: The _scp_ command needs two arguments: source and destination.

Comment: Thank you for response but there is not error during file transfer issue arises when file transfer is completed chmod is not running and ./ is not working scp command is stucked after tranfering file

Comment: Anyone have any solution for the issue. #Rinzwind My scp command is working properly but the point is when i run multiple commands in scp than only scp command is working. If you have another command or alternative to this command please help me to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

scp works with source and destination. If you want to copy a file from another computer than this is the source and the destination is your local computer

```
scp user@<foreign-computer>:/some-source-dir/file /some-destination-dir/on-your-computer/.
```

This will copy to your computer. After that you can adjust rights.

If you want to copy a file to another computer then you cant change the rights from your host. You need to login to this other host and change the rights.

Another approach would be to use ansible or salt, but this has to be installed first.

Comment: I agree with your answer for scp. My scp command is working properly but another commands are not working. I want to run all these commands one by one. And at another end i don't have the credentials so what kind of rights you are saying to change there is no right on the other host every right is working on the 777. I don't get my solution !